# Will angular automatically update if I run higher version(angular 6) project in my machine(lower version angular 5)?

Tags: angular, upgrade

I have an Angular 6 project. I want to run it in a other machine , which is already installed angular 5. If I run the angular 6 project in that machine using 'npm, install', Is it upgrade from angular 5 to angular 6?  I have other projects which are developed using angular 5. Will those projects get affect if I run the angular 6 project in (angular 5) machine?

angular 6 project package.json

```
{
  "name": "order-tracking",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4": "^0.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: it will not automatically update, in angular 6 they have provided a CLI command ng-update which will take care of updating the angular as well as other dependencies to the latest version

Comment: show us your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Just run command `npm install` and it will install all your angular 6 dependencies.

As your project is already build using Angular 6, Need not to do anything special here.
You need `ng update` only when your application was built on angular lower version and you want to migrate to angular 6.